# Add "Top of Page" link to a Script

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this plugin to make a list of all the Categories on my Wordpress blog :

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=T6rvtwkS

The script can be seen in action here :

www.animefushigi.com/full-anime-list

Now, I want to add a link to Top of page under each set of alphebetical listings, so right after each `</ul>`

I want to add this :

```
<a href="javascript:scroll(0,0)">
Top
</a>
```

Where and How can I implement that in the plugin script???

Comment: why the heck use javascript for this ? is <a href="#top"> not good enough anymore ? :-)

Comment: Is the home key on the keyboard (or equivalent) not good enough anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<a href="#[LETTER]">
```

(see [link](http://www.voober.com/anime-series-list/#R))

Comment: Yes that can work, but where do I implement that inside the plugin script so that the TOP link appears above each letter box heading. 

Here is example of what I mean  :

http://www.voober.com/anime-series-list/